# "[drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting"

Tags: 14.04, kernel, intel-graphics

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 server on Dell Latitude E7440 and then installed Cinnamon 2.4.5 on top of it. The laptop has an external monitor connected through Display Port and a docking station.

On the first day the system worked perfectly.

On the second day, the system booted to the login screen (leaving the external screen empty but otherwise seemed to be under X11's control), it then let me type my username and password but then X exits, shows a bit of VT1 with errors then gets back to the login page.

I found the following error in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
[drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
```

I found a page which claims to solve this error for 12.04 in the second comment in [this bugzilla thread on libreoffice.org](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=73694#c2), but I don't understand how to apply this patch on my system. So far I failed to find the source file `intel_dp.c` in any Ubuntu source package.

Does anyone know how can I apply this patch on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer - the file was inside `linux-source-3.13.0.tar.bz2` which comes in package `linux-source-3.13.0`. I filed a request to include this in the Ubuntu kernel at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1403275